# Are there manufacturers of bulk materials with specific electromagnetic properties?

Tags: rf, materials, dielectric, reference-materials

For the purpose of testing some antennas, I am looking for a manufacturer of materials with specific dielectric constants and loss tangents.

I have been googling for å few hours, but either I do not know the correct terms to use, or such manufacturers do not exist. The few manufacturers I find seem to be primarily focused on providing low loss materials, which is the opposite of what I need.

Specifically, I am looking to obtain materials (preferably solid and not liquid) with a relative permittivity between 3 and 8 in the range 2 to 6 GHz. It is also important for my application that the material has a large (>0.75) loss tangent. I considered using Methanol, which has a  relative permittivity close to what I need and which can be adjusted by temperature, but I would really prefer to not having to mess around with liquids. Besides, its relative permittivity is not completely ideal.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: I'd start by doing a literature search on the general topic to find researchers discussing terms in ways you care about. Then I'd narrow the list down and make a few phone calls or write some emails to the corresponding authors of papers I'd read in the process. Some of them will give you some very good advice about how to move forward to the next step. Take it.